# docker can't start container correctly on mac

Tags: docker

[image]

I try to run a new container with ubuntu:16.04 and start it.
After I start it, there is not any error&warning message, but I can't see any container run of the "docker ps"

Comment: How did you `run` your container?

Comment: start "container name"

Comment: This is how you `start` a container which has been already created and has exited. What parameters did you use when you first run it?

Comment: I believe that you have run your container without `-it` parameters and now every time you try to `start` it again, it exits immediately. Try to use `docker run -it ubuntu:16.04`

Comment: `docker logs <containerName>` will show logs from the last run, which is helpful when troubleshooting containers which are shutting down unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run docker container as a background by using **-d** parameter

**docker run -i -t image_name -d /bin/bash**

```
as an example  
docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Also in above image, when you are running **docker ps -a** it will show all containers (running and stopped) and if you use **docker ps** command then it will show only running containers, because of that it's not showing you already exited one.

Comment: But I don't know why what's wrong when my create a container. Why can't I just key "docker run ubuntu:16.04"

Comment: If you run "docker run ubuntu:16.04" it will start docker container in console, when you press ctrl+c then docker container will stop, hence you need to start container in background process with -d flag.